# Installation of RAM making MBP slow

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

Is there any reason why the installation of a RAM, larger than recommended, cause MBP to slow during startup and during normal working?

I am trying to understand the cases I didn't foresee when I went for higher than recommended RAM.

---

I have:

- mid-2012 13 inch MBP;
- running macOS Sierra;
- recommended RAM for this machine is 8GB but I installed 2X8 (aka 16) GB RAM replacing my earlier 2X2 (aka 4) GB RAM.

Comment: Memory does not necessarily speed up your computer - if it wasn't using the full 4GB to begin with, adding 12GB more isn't going to make any difference.  What you should be checking is your Disk Activity in activity monitor.

Comment: @Allan: It was swapping a lot earlier. 4 GB was full. I did later realize though that I needed only 8 GB instead of 16. Also, I'll concede that I didn't really exclusively check disk activity. But it would have been high already because of swaps. No?

Comment: @Allan: In particular, I want to know if there is some case when installing a *higher than recommend* RAM cause a slowdown.

Comment: Is there a case?  Yes - when the OS cannot address the higher memory (32bit)  However, this is not the case.  macOS can support 64GB of RAM on the Mac Pro.

Comment: Was it swapping or was there high disk activity?  If your drive is failing, it's only going to get worse.

Comment: @Allan: It was swapping for sure. But it may be possible that the drive is failing too. The device is already 4 years old.

Comment: That's the angle I was going for.  Have a look at this post:  My mac is getting slow](http://bit.ly/2fPjkBn)

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons.

Firsts, new RAM can be slower than your original RAM. Compare original RAM specification and the one you installed. For Macs manufacturers usually have specially tested and tuned RAM modules. Anything cheap will actually decrease performance.

Secondly, Mac allocates as much swap as you have RAM. Earlier your Mac allocated 4GB at start, now it has to allocate 16GB. If you do not have SSD, this will be much slower because the swap file has to be written to disk at start.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick in your answer... My new RAM's specifications weren't poorer than the older one. Also, shouldn't the swap come in use only when the RAM has been fully used? My 16 GB RAM is rarely crossing the 8 GB usage mark, so swap shouldn't really be an issue even when it is 16 GB.

Comment: This is incorrect.  macOS doesn't allocate 16GB of swap because you have 16GB of RAM.  It adds pager files that range from 64 to 512MB as needed.